# how can we add a group of buttons and change them when clicked on next and previous button

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

This is my current code for 2 sets of buttons how can we add next and previous functionality to them.

```
   <div id="chart-section-wrapper" class="container">
    <div id="chart-section">
        <div class="overall-btns col my-3">
        <!-- Buttons -->  
            <!-- set-1 -->           
            <button class="selector-button" name="button-default-1">
                <i class="icon bi bi-droplet-half"></i><span>Albanian</span>
            </button>          
        
            <button class="selector-button" name="button-default-2">
                <i class="icon bi bi-droplet-half"></i><span>Arabic</span>
            </button>          
       
            <button class="selector-button" name="button-default-3">
                <i class="icon bi bi-droplet-half"></i><span>Armenian</span>
            </button>        
      
             <!-- set-2 --> 
            <button class="selector-button" name="button-default-4">
                <i class="icon bi bi-droplet-half"></i><span>Azerbaijani</span>
            </button>
             <button class="selector-button" name="button-default-4">
                <i class="icon bi bi-droplet-half"></i><span>Azerbaijani</span>
            </button>
            <button class="selector-button" name="button-default-4">
                <i class="icon bi bi-droplet-half"></i><span>Azerbaijani</span>
            </button>
        
          <!-- Next-btn -->      
        <div class="next-button-parent text-right mb-3 col-3">
            <button class="next-button" id="next-button">Next </button>
        </div>
        <!-- -btn -->
         <div class="next-button-parent text-right mb-3 col-3">
            <button class="next-button" id="next-button">Prev </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

how can I make this like when clicked on the next button the set-2 buttons should appear and when clicked on previous the set-1 buttons should appear.

Comment: any trials want to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's probably not the cleanest solution, but it might gives you a good idea how you can solve it: https://codepen.io/chri_joh/pen/wvgXQgx

```
var current_position = 1;
var max_blocks = 2;

function show_button_set(direction){
  if(direction === '+'){
    current_position += 1;
    if(current_position > max_blocks) current_position = 1;
  } else {
    current_position -= 1;
    if(current_position < 1) current_position = max_blocks;
  }
  
  document.getElementById('buttonset1').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('buttonset2').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('buttonset'+current_position).style.display = 'block';
}
```

in the solution i basically wrapped the two button blocks, it's also built that you can easily extend it with more blocks

Comment: but when using media queries its overlappig

Comment: i actually didn't take care of any styling, i basically wanted to show you, how you can solve this problem - and actually not sure though what is overlapping as there was no css added in your code snippet

Answer (score 0):

In order to show set 1 when clicked on next button and set 2 when clicked on previous button you could change your HTML as:

```
      <!-- Next-btn -->      
    <div class="next-button-parent text-right mb-3 col-3">
        <button onclick="show_button_set('1')" class="next-button" id="next-        button">Next </button>
    </div>
    <!-- -btn -->
     <div class="next-button-parent text-right mb-3 col-3">
        <button onclick="show_button_set('2')" class="next-button" id="next-button">Prev </button>
    </div>
```

and you could use a script as below:

```
function show_button_set(set){
  document.getElementById('buttonset1').style.display = set==1? 'block':'none';
  document.getElementById('buttonset2').style.display = set==2? 'block':'none';
}
```